# Integrate non-free (with permission) / differently licenced logos in GPL repository

Tags: licensing, open-source, gpl, android, creative-commons

I'm planning to open source an Android app that I developed against the API of a (small regional) social network.
This app is the 'official' version for the website and thus allowed to use the logo and name of the website.

I plan to open source it under the GPL, but:

1. I cannot put the logo or name under the GPL (I don't own the rights)
2. I  plan to integrate icons from the Android Material Design Icon library (Creative Commons)

Is there any proper way to do this while keeping everything in a single repository on Github?
(Given that the app is free I can't exactly consult a lawyer.)

Comment: If someone forks your app, would they also have the right to use the logo of the social network?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I explicitely had to be given permission to use the name&logo - so no, I'd say forking it would not give someone the right to use it...